# How good is the vision of diurnal birds of prey really?

Tags: ornithology, vision

Diurnal raptors (especially eagles and hawks) are commonly thought to have incredible visual acuity, up to 5 or 8 times higher than a typical human. However, I haven't been able to find any scientific evidence of such measurements, beyond popular science websites and unsourced Wikipedia articles. The actual scientific estimates I've seen (such as [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1084952119301004), see the results referenced in part 9) indicate that their vision is not really overwhelmingly better than our own, with even exceptionally large raptors like the wedge-tailed eagle only having twice the visual acuity of an average human, and many small sized raptors like falcons having actually substantially poorer vision. I understand that eye size is important (even with their proportionately large eyes they're still not larger than ours, and that places a maximum limit on spatial resolution)

They also have lower achromatic contrast sensitivity than a human (although their ability to distinguish chromatic contrast is far higher).

So are there any actual bird species with 5 times better vision than a human or is it just a pop culture/folklore myth?

Comment: Helpful paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1084952119301004. part of the problem is "acuity" is not a perfect term, some eagles can see things from 5 times the DISTANCE humans can.